How do I set fan speed in asus laptop to turbo?
AsusTUF-F15. I use different ways to control fans speed if you have any experience to set fan speed to turbo mode please say it to me.

As written there is nothing here to offer any help. What have you already done? What errors or messages did each produce.? What is the version of Ubuntu you are using? This link will guide you to making a better question. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Try nbfc (This is a C port of Stefan Hirschmann's NoteBook FanControl).
There should be in pull-request the right config file. If not, look somewhere else for the config file.
